# How to extract Facebook page likes and profile picture from Facebook API output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, parsing, nokogiri

I'm using Nokogiri 1.7.1 and Rails 4.2.4 in my application. When I view Facebook's source code, there is no HTML or CSS allowing me to select and scrape the text.

Facebook is using React code:

```
// ....
showSponsorTaggerButtonNUX:false,showSponsorTaggerDirectBoost:false,showSponsorTaggerSponsorRelationship:false}},attachmentsConfig:{STATUS:{canScrapeShare:true,canAttachLocation:false,enabled:true,largeTextThreshold:85,profileID:null,profileName:null,profileURI:null,profilePicSrc:"https://scontent.fsvg1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/c12.0.40.40/p40x40/10354686_10150004552801856_220367501106153455_n.jpg?oh=3ad0945d50cb5c25455167972e2cb9c6&oe=5A0CA7F8"
// ....
```

For instance I found `profilePicSrc`. I tried using `at_css` and `xpath`. I might doing it wrong or it can't scrape them because there is no CSS or HTML that Nokogiri can select/find.

I managed to get these details from the Facebook API:

```
{
   "id": "7270241753",
   "name": "YouTube",
   "cover": {
      "cover_id": "10156001238986754",
      "offset_x": 0,
      "offset_y": 0,
      "source": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/14591676_10156001238986754_7091829954587846661_n.jpg?oh=b5bc4ca11e6a5d47f18b798eb38cc176&oe=59DBEC50",
      "id": "10156001238986754"
   },
   "fan_count": 82634405,
   "picture": {
      "data": {
         "is_silhouette": false,
         "url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/19424472_10156001229851754_375700039380897185_n.jpg?oh=965b50ea998545bcbcb99fb90b3ba606&oe=59CEF703"
      }
   }
}
```

How can I select the profile picture, name, the number of likes the page has and its big header image from this output?

Comment: You are not allowed to scrape Facebook to extract data in the first place. If you want to interact with pages on Facebook - then use their API.

Comment: thanks @CBroe, I have never used Facebook API before. What would the API link be for getting a page's details?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/

Comment: Thanks a bunch @CBroe could you please take a look at the question once more. I have updated with some outputs.

Comment: That’s JSON, and once you decode it, you got a nested data structure. How to access that in ruby/RoR, I don’t know - but that should be easy enough to research, and is not Facebook-specific.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". Your question isn't asked well. What did you try? Why didn't it work? Nokogiri doesn't process JavaScript so it will not help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As nokogiri doesn't process javascript, I end up using `Facebook open graph` to get page data in json format and did a `JSON.load(open(link))` and parsed them from the output.